# Workarounds for tSalesforceOutputBulkExec NPE in case of empty flow

Tags: salesforce, integration, talend

This post is not a question, just something I want to share with anyone concerned by Salesforce integration.
With TDI 6.3.1, having an empty flow as input cause tSalesforceOutputBulkExec to fail with a null pointer exception.
It was not the case with 6.2.x and previous versions.

Fortunately, there is at least 2 workarounds:

1- **store the flow in a tHashOutput**, then link it to a tHashInput with a conditional link and finally, link the tHashInput  to tSalesforceOutputBulkExec:[image]
The conditional expression is the following:
`((Integer)globalMap.get("tHashOutput_12_NB_LINE")) > 0`

Use this workaround for a flow of limited size else you risk to encounter a memory exception.
Also tick the "Clear cache after reading" option for tHashInput component if you don't need to reuse the content anymore after this operation.

2- **replace the tSalesforceOutputBulkExec** component by a tSalesforceOutputBulk linked to a tSalesforceOutputExec with a conditional link:
[image]

In this case, the conditional expression is:
`((Integer)globalMap.get("tSalesforceOutputBulk_1_NB_LINE")) > 0`

No limitation regarding the flow size with this solution as tSalesforceOutputBulk use a file (the same as for tSalesforceOutputBulkExec), so you may prefer it if you have to manage huge flows.

Advantage, for these 2 solutions compared to tSalesforceOutputBulkExec is you have fewer calls to the Salesforce Bulk API (because you will not make calls for empty flows anymore).

Hope this will help you.

TRF

Comment: Consider making a contribution to the docs: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/salesforce

Comment: Actually, with the 2nd solution you are limited to 10000 rows or 10MB of data. If you have more rows than that, you need to split your input, and send batches of 10k rows per call.

Comment: That's the same for both. This is a Salesforce governor limit.

Comment: You are right, I was thinking of tSalesforceOuptut which doesn't limit the number of rows you can send.